# KSOAP stop running at transport.call() method

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am having the situation that ksoap2 is stopping at the transport.call() method.

I am not able to find any solution after searching so your help is my only hope.

I know that the transport.call() has stopped because my log only shows up to:

`Log.i(TAG, "start4");`

Thank you for your help. Here's more current code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.i(TAG, "begining");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tele = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tele);
    request res = new request();
    Log.i(TAG, "start");
    //try{
        Log.i(TAG, "before Soapobject");
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Log.i(TAG, "start1");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Log.i(TAG, "start2");
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = false;
        Log.i(TAG, "start3");
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        Log.i(TAG, "start4");
    try{
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        Log.i(TAG, "transpoartCALL");
        SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
        Log.i(TAG, "beforesetTele");
        res.setTele(resultString.getProperty("tele").toString());
        tele.setText(res.getTele().toString());
        Log.i(TAG, "testing");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: what's you are get in logcat?

Comment: hi mahdi what do u mean by what i get?

Comment: such as error or warning, if you get from server or application

Comment: i have tons of W/System.err. one of it is W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: did you set internet permission on manifets?

Comment: yes, i did add the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>. And then i tried ur suggested answer but it still giving me the same err

Comment: @HoeLuen Check your namespace, methodname, soap version.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
 HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

To

```
AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
```

Comment: @Hoe Luen Do yo get any exception or something? and Is your api developed in .net?

Comment: thx for your answer @Nisarg i have solved the problem by using thread

Comment: @Hoe Luen No problem, did it help ?